# bash script to compare file names in one directory with file names in another while ignoring file extensions

Tags: bash, gnupg

I am trying to compare the files in one directory with those in another. Let's take directories test 1 and test2. If test 1 contains a file named 123.JPG and if test 2 contains a file named 123.JPG.gpg I would then take no course of action: 123.JPG has already been encrypted. However if no match was successful I would then run gpg to encrypt 123.JPG.

I found this script elsewhere which I tried to modify to achieve the above but to no avail:

```
cd source
for x in *; do
  set -- "…/dest/${x%.*}".*
  if [ $# -eq 1 ] && ! [ -e "$1" ]; then
    echo "$x has not been converted"
  elif [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "$x has been converted to more than one output file: " "$@"
  else
    echo "$x has been converted to $1"
  fi
done
```

Can anyone please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU's `find` and you can use the `printf` option, then the follwing command:

```
comm -23 <(find A -type f -printf '%f.gpg\n'|sort) <(find B -type f -printf '%f\n'|sort)
```

will give you a list of missing files:

If directory A is:

```
A
├── 123.JPG
├── 456.JPG
└── 789.JPG
```

And directory B is:

```
B
├── 123.JPG.gpg
└── 456.JPG.gpg
```

The output would be `789.JPG.gpg` which is the missing encrypted file - it **does not exist** in directory B, and a file with a similar name but without the extension, **does exist** in directory A.

You can then use the result list to encrypt the missing files.

Please notice that this command works recursively.

Comment: Thanks Rany. When I run this I get this error -ash: syntax error: unexpected "(". Is that because I am on bash rather then zsh?

Comment: No. That should work on Bash. Please check that you are running the same command.

Comment: The error message suggests you are running `ash`, which indeed does not support this non-POSIX syntax extension.

Comment: Thanks both for your help.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein I made changes to my set up so that I would need to use your comm command to encrypt my pictures (I now rely on its recursiveness). So after I have run the comm command what do I need to write to encrypt the pictures? Where do I write gpg --encrypt -r xyz@xyz.com?

Comment: @spesmagna Use a `while` loop to iterate over the results and do whatever you wish. In the following snippet I print `"$file"` on every iteration: `while IFS= read -r file; do printf '%s\n' "$file"; done < <(comm -23 <(find A -type f -printf '%f.gpg\n'|sort) <(find B -type f -printf '%f\n'|sort))`

Comment: Many thanks again for your help @RanyAlbegWein. I'm most grateful. I just made a minor modification to your code instead of do printf '%s\n' "$file" I wrote do printf '%s\n' $(basename "$file" .gpg) that way when I change printf to gpg it encrypts the non encrypted pictures.

Comment: You're welcome! You can use `printf '%s\n' "${file%.gpg}"` instead of `basename` here.

Answer (score 1):

So, for each file X in the `test1` directory, you want to check whether the file named `X.gpg` exists in the `test2` directory, and if not, execute a GPG command to create the file in `test2`.

```
for source in test1/*
do
    target="test2/$(basename "$source").gpg"
    if [ ! -f "$target" ]
    then
        …run gpg to encrypt "$source" into "$target"…
    fi
done
```

Comment: A slight refinement: Run `gpg` as `gpg ... <source> ... <target>.TMP ; mv <target>.TMP <target>`. The `mv` is [somewhat] atomic. This prevents `<target>` from being malformed/partial in the event of a system crash, power failure, or the script being interrupted via `<ctrl-c>`. If any of those occur, the script can be rerun and it will redo the partials and finish the ones that weren't done.

Comment: Thanks for helping Jonathan. However, I don't seem to be able to get this to work. When I run this script GPG ends up encrypting all the files. So even if test1 contains CIMG0614.JPG and if test2 contains CIMG0614.JPG.gpg the script encrypts again CIMG0614.JPG. I understand what the script above does except for this part: if [ ! -f "target" ]. What exactly does this do?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Probably meant "$target" instead of "target". [ or test is the POSIX test command. It can do simple tests on files and strings. In bash, you should use the more powerful [[ instead and ban [ for sake of consistency. [[ can do pattern 
                matching, is faster and safer to use. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: There is/was a typo there.  It should be `$target` inside the quotes.  Sorry!

Comment: Hello. I have made changes to my setup and would now need for the check between test1 and test2 to be performed recursively i.e. within subdirectories as the .jpg files are now long in the top directory (I'm using Exiftool to sort the pictures by year and by month). Can anyone advise how the script written by @JonathanLeffler should be modified? Thank you